# Is there a way to extend a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitch

I've recently started coding a chatbot for Twitch based on [this](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/irc).

I'd like the function `onMessageHandler` to be extended to a seperate file so I can keep all the if-statements in that file for clarity reasons.

I'd really like to know how I'd have to do that if there is a way.

Comment: hi, could you show us examples of what you have already tried?

Comment: are you trying to import `bot.js` into another file? You can do something like `const botjs = require("./bot.js");` and use the function like `botjs.onMessageHandler()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about creating an `utils` folder.

1- Require you new file:

```
const utils = require('./utils/onMessageHandler.js');
```

2 - Use same function as in the example, adding `client` as an argument, and export it (rollDice function could be here also):

```
 function onMessageHandler (target, context, msg, self, client) {...}
 function rollDice () {...}
 exports.onMessageHandler = onMessageHandler;
```

3- Call your function:

```
client.on('message', utils.onMessageHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend or inherit functions in Javascript, or in many languages that I know of. You could however import a file and use the functions inside of it like this:

```
const botjs = require("./bot.js"); 
botjs.onMessageHandler(/*args here*/);
```

Comment: to clarify, you can extend or inherit classes, not functions.

Answer (score 0):

at the bottom in the file where your function is:

```
exports.onMessageHandler = onMessageHandler;
```

at the top of where you want to use the function:

```
const { onMessageHandler } = require(relative path to file where function is);
```